# Flutter Web: Open app on android if installed or send user to play store, open website on all other platforms

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Prevent android user from using the website, redirect the user to the app if installed or play store page but allow the user to use the website on all other platforms.

Comment: see https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

Comment: How do I use that in this case?

Comment: It's simple but you have a lot to do, take a look at the document

Comment: Am already using dynamic links...I just want the web app should redirect to the app on android preventing android users to use web app instead of app.

Comment: use must create your own protocol, When the user came to your url page, java script check your device and if device is android try to open ur protocol like MRT://url/params, and if app exist in phone the program opens  and now u can parse protocol parms data and go to the page you want

Comment: What if I don't want to pass any params, and just open the app? Can I do it deep link? trying to open the deep link will automatically open app, right?

Comment: you can use [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) to open and check if the specific app is installed or not and open by using it's package name. e.g com.facebook.katana , com.instagram.android.  and use this package [store_redirect](https://pub.dev/packages/store_redirect) to redirect is app is not installed.

Comment: It's not supported on web...I need for web

Comment: Did you find any solution?